# javascript caller onproperty change

Tags: javascript

I have a form element who's disabled property is being changed somewhere and I cannot seem to find where it is by looking through the code and disabling code which makes changes to the disabled property.

I have searched here and found 'caller' and tried to implement this but it is not firing off.

What I am trying to do is to determine which function changed the property of the element to disabled.

```
onchange = "alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`onchange = "alert('caller is ' + arguments.callee.caller.toString());"`

Comment: Totaly outdated in '16